# How to pass-in form action name as a variable into axios ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I been following this Laracasts Vue tutorial: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/20

The Form and Error classes are a great improvement for any ajax application.
I would like to use the the same "onsubmit" function for POST and  PATCH request types, but I am running into one issue:

This works:

```
onSubmit(action = 'post'){
            this.form['post']('/user').then(response => this.newRecord = response);
        }
```

but if I try to suplay `action` as a variable it doesn't  work, can anybody point me to what I am doing wrong?

```
onSubmit(action = 'post'){
            this.form[action]('/user').then(response => this.newRecord = response);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding console logging to check the value of `action`? Or a `debugger` statement?

Comment: @skirtle, I just did console.loged it. My bad, it is an event that is passed in., not string.  `Event {isTrusted: true, type: "submit", target: form, currentTarget: form, eventPhase: 2, …}`. Will need to figure a work-around.